# Integrating Internet Download Manager, which installed in Virtual Box, with Firefox or Chromium, installed on Ubuntu 12.04 (host OS)

Tags: virtualbox

Maybe my question be kind of strange but i hope i can get a good answer.

I have installed Win XP on virtual box in ubuntu 12.04, and I installed [IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) on it.
So, I want when i clicked on a downloadable link in Ubuntu (the host OS), the [IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) can grab the link and download it in Win XP (the guest os)!

Before that I wanna thank you.

Comment: If you set up clipboard monitoring it could work on copying the link.

Comment: Thank you so much. But is't there a way to grab the link when i left clicked in the host OS.

Comment: No, left-click integration you seek works by having your browser send certain links to the target program (IDM in your case). Problem is there is no way to for the host to communicate with the guest OS, other than the standard stuff that is possible in LAN. So referring to a program in a guest OS is too much of a long shot.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259228/alternative-to-internet-download-manager-6-x-x-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I used to use IDM on XP.  I really doubt if it will work from a VM, as the VM is pretty separated from the host system.

If you use Firefox, I'd recommend trying out "DownThemAll!", a download manager plugin.  I've been using it, and it works very well for me.  You can download all links on a page, or a selection of links, like IDM.  It seems fast, and so far, has worked well for me.

I don't know if it's available for any other browsers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try sharing your downloads folder with your virtual machine.  Point IDM at this folder.  This way you can download with one browser and have your downloads in one place between machines.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

## It seems impossible.

This is not an answer, but I'm encouraging you to take the advantage of [ProzGUI](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/prozgui/prozgui_2.0.5betaa-2_i386.deb), [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashgot/) and [Video Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) on Firefox as an alternative to Internet Download Manager.

I'm working on something like this:

[image]

You can also try other downloaders like FatRat, MultiGet, WxDownload Fast instead of ProzGUI