# Which download manager gives similar functionallity like Internet Download Manager for Windows?

Tags: download-manager

I require **a single download manager** which has the following functionality:

- Download acceleration.
- Firefox integration
- Download streaming online videos.
- Download management.
- Automated system shutdown.
- Pause/resume supports for my downloads